# Boolean Type Method

Tags: java

Although I have already add **"return true"** & **"return false"** at the **"boolean Method"**, but I keep getting error ***"add return"***. Does anybody know what the problem is?

The question is: "Given an unsorted array that may contain duplicates. Also given a number k which is smaller than size of array. Write a function that returns true if array contains duplicates within k distance."

```
    public static void main (String[] args){

        int[] arr = {2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 7, 8, 5, 4, 9};
        int k = 3;

        System.out.println(duplicateKDistance(arr, k));

    }   
    public static boolean duplicateKDistance(int[] array, int m){

        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            for(int j=i+1; j<=m; ){          // if you add "j++", it will be dead code here :)              
                if (array[i] == array[j])
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;   
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `j<=m;` or even `i<array.length` will never be true (for instance for non positive `m` or empty array `[]`)?

Comment: Your logic is off, and you'll want to think through the method's logic on paper once again, walking through the necessary steps on paper.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? For example, what is the connection between `m` and the length of the array?

Comment: What will your method return if `array.length` is 0?

Comment: @pbabcdefp : This is the question: **"Given an unsorted array that may contain duplicates. Also given a number k which is smaller than size of array. Write a function that returns true if array contains duplicates within k distance."**

Comment: Thank you. I (sort of) get it now. Does "within k distance" mean "among the first k elements"?

Comment: @pbabcdefp - it means the duplicate one should be in distance of **k** or less, not more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the return outside of the For loop. The way you have it setup at the moment your entire program assumes you enter the loop. If you never enter that For loop the program will never have a return. So Java wants you to place the return false outside of the first for loop. You should probably take out that else return false.... as it will always trigger if your if statement is not true. By having the return false outside the loop your logic behind why you need the else is now captured and implied by you not entering into the if statement within your second for loop.

```
  public static boolean duplicateKDistance(int[] array, int m){

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<=m; j++){        

            if (array[i] == array[j])
                return true;

        }   
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Don't you need the `j++` in the nested for loop condition? Otherwise this looks good.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, If we add **j++**, it will be deadcode. It will never run. So I removed it. Also, thank you for you suggestions; I will next time :)

Comment: I didn't check the j++ problem was more a comment on the return types. It won't work because j is always going to be i+1....j needs to be incremented

Comment: @LeighGriffin - You are right. I should add **j++**. I don't know why at first java gave me warning that it is a dead code!

Answer (score 1):

**You need to change logic try following code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = { 2, 5, 7, 4, 2, 7, 8, 5, 4, 9 };
        int k = 3;

        System.out.println(FindZero.duplicateKDistance(arr, k));

    }

    public static boolean duplicateKDistance(int[] array, int m) {

        boolean flag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= m;) { // if you add "j++", it will be dead
                                            // code here :)

                if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you only return a value if you ever enter any of the loops.

If none of the loop conditions are never met, you'll never reach a `return` statement. Simply add one at the end of the method:

```
public static boolean duplicateKDistance(int[] array, int m){

    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<=m; ){          // if you add "j++", it will be dead code here :)

            if (array[i] == array[j])
                return true;
            else 
                return false;   
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Even this is no good. Why use for loops much less nested for loops if the loop will always exit on the first turn of the loop?

Comment: In this case, it will always return "false".

Comment: @Hengameh: again, you must think through your logic before committing code.

Comment: Who is up-voting this answer? There's no way that the posted code will produce anything of use.